# svg doesn't show on canvas in example, react

Tags: reactjs, svg, canvas

I'm pretty inexperienced with the canvas element. The most I've used it for was a game back in 2013, where I could just freely use requestAnimationFrame().

I wanted to write a game like this again, but I am doing it while embedded in a website which uses React, and none of the animations seem to update anymore.

Anyway, I thought maybe I could use the following article and its discussions of svg animation to animate more manually. I barely modified the code at all from the original article.

**canvas.html**

```
<canvas id="canvas"  width="500" height="500">
    <svg id="animatedSvg" width="500" height="500" viewPort="0 0 500 500" version="1.1"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect id="rect" x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"  style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)">
    <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="x" from="-100" to="120"
        dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </rect>
  <script src="./anim.js"></script> 
</svg>
```

**anim.js**

```
setInterval(function(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

if(Update){

    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    draw(canvas);
}

},10);

function draw(ele){
    var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(ele.outerHTML, "image/svg+xml");
var x = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
    //html add textnodes before and after elements ignore them.
    if(x[i].nodeName == "#text" || x[i].nodeName == "script" || x[i].nodeName == "style"){ continue; }
    switch(x[i].nodeName)
    {
        case "rect":
            svgDrawRect(x[i]);
            break;
        case "text": svgDrawText(x[i]);
            break;
        case "svg": draw(x[i]);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

I've just placed a script tag to reference the Javascript, but I can't see the actual rectangle, even if I change the style. What I can see is the rectangle iterating across its x range, but it's invisible. What's going on?

At the end of the day, I might just use react-canvas instead.

Link ->

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas#Adding_svg_animations_to_a_canvas

Comment: Please edit the question and add your code, ideally a [mcve] otherwise we can't really tell what you've done wrong.

Comment: the `canvas` element is a void element, just like an `img`. You don't put other HTML elements inside of it. SVG is one way to present graphics to the user, the canvas is another way to present graphics to the user, and they're mutually exclusive: either an element is a vector graphics element with animations, CSS, and JS access like any other HTML element, or it's a canvas2d bitmap that runs independently of the page it's on, with only a JS API to manipulate its content.

Comment: Curious why Mozilla embedded other HTML elements inside a `canvas`, inside their docs then. See the link I had previously.

Comment: This article... it is so misleading and carries so much hacks that everyone with an even more horrible idea keep adding to it... For the particular case you linked, they only use the svg events, they don't render the svg. If you look at the example before you'll see they use a custom svg parser (their elements are not even svg ones, but html unknown... @Mike, yes you can add non-rendered elements inside a canvas, that was originally thougt as a way to provide some inpaired friendly UI, not to ugly hacks like this...

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific: you can add them, but they don't "do" anything: you'll never see them. As I recall the MDN pages are all wiki based so it should be possible to just edit it back to something that's correct.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think of that, for about 2 years now, when it only shown an hackish way of drawing DOM elements through `<foreignObject>` (at this time only supported by FF for security reasons) and the only viable edit I can think of would be to remove it entirely. Since then, they did add some *Limitations* paragraph, which to me is not enough, but the evil is already done, a lot of new comers think this works because *Hey! it's on MDN* and then come here (on SO) asking why it doesn't.. And now I see they decided to make it a stack of all the worst hacks you can think of...

Comment: Preaching to the choir: I work on the foundation side (not the main side) of said company, and I run into MDN pages that are really questionable often enough.